# What are the factors that make the Belgian government the most supportive towards Palestine and South Africa's lawsuit against Israel?

Tags: europe, international-court-of-justice, belgium

> EU voices endorsing South Africa's lawsuit are so far sparse and
> isolated.
>
> Belgium's Deputy Prime Minister Petra De Sutter, whose government is
> seen as the most supportive of Palestinians in Europe, said on Tuesday
> she would urge Belgium to formally back South Africa's case.
>
> The Belgian government, a complex coalition of seven parties, has not
> yet endorsed de Sutter's call but has committed €5 million in
> additional funding for the International Criminal Court (ICC) -
> another international court based in the Hague often confused for the
> ICJ - to investigate possible war crimes in the conflict between
> Israel and Hamas.
>
> Irish Taoiseach Leo Varadkar, whose government has been hailed as one
> of the most supportive of Palestinian statehood across Europe, has
> ruled out any possibility Ireland would join the case, despite
> pressure from Irish lawmakers.

https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2024/01/12/where-do-eu-countries-stand-on-south-africas-genocide-case-against-israel

What are the factors that make the Belgian government the most supportive towards Palestine and South Africa's lawsuit against Israel? Aside the fact that the Belgian government is a member of the Hague convention, what are the things that explains why it's one of the few voices in Europe supportive of the lawsuit against Israel at the ICJ?

Comment: Speculation, hence why I am not putting it in an answer: while Germany's biggest genocide was against Jews, and most non-German countries focus on the Holocaust because of its effects on Europe as a whole and their occasional collaboration, Belgium's biggest genocide was against Congolese people, more or less on the same continent as Israel and Palestine. And theirs was an external genocide rather than an (initially) internal one, which is the kind of genocide being alleged against Israel. So the focus of their feeling of culpability might be different.

Comment: I'd add 3 more considerations.  First, having an extremely fragile coalition may mean that one party's *important* issue, may trounce other parties' *relative* objections.  Second, Belgium has also had some exposure to genocide considerations thru the sequels of its colonization in Rwanda.  Third, if you look at  [Sabra massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabra_and_Shatila_massacre#Role_of_various_parties) you'll see some victims sued in Belgian courts.  Maybe they have legislation similar to the US's *Alien Tort Statute*?  Question is not bad, but seems hard to answer definitely.

Comment: Belgium's near-neighbour the Netherlands (which shares a language with the northern half of Belgium - De Sutter is Flemish) also has particular sensitivity to genocide thanks to its perceived [failures to prevent genocide in Bosnia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutchbat), so this may also influence Flemish positions.